# Convert binary from ms access into Image for Imagelist

Tags: c#, image, ms-access, bitmap, binary

I have just converted a bitmap thumbnail into binary code to store into my MS Access Database. I am now trying to convert that binary data back into the image format to store into my Imagelist. My code right now is.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        vcon.Open();
        string get = "Select Path, Images FROM IMGSTR";
        OleDbCommand cmdget = new OleDbCommand(get, vcon);
        OleDbDataReader reader;
        reader = cmdget.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            string path = reader["Path"].ToString();

            // should I convert binary into a string?
            string thumbnail = reader["Images"].ToString();

            // How to convert the binary data from the
            // MS database back to a bitmap image.

            //I need to convert the binary back to bitmap to work
            //in this imagelist.
            this.imageList1.Images.Add(thumbnail);

        }



    }
```

If anyone can help me that would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast it to a byte array:

```
Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream((byte[]) reader["Images"]))
```